# Previous date with condition Google Spreadsheet formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, counting, gs-vlookup

I have a list of users with dates of they visited the website.  I need to calculate the first visit date for each record with the condition that if a user misses a month, it is considered new and the date should be new.
How can I calculate it?

Here is an example. I need to calculate the First visit column.

```
Visit Date  User    First visit
10/15/19    User1   10/15/19
11/13/19    User1   10/15/19
01/07/20    User1   01/07/20
02/03/20    User1   01/07/20
```

Comment: Could you share a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, as well as the outcome you expect?

Comment: Here is the copy - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HSbqxmDqE0qzL6vIwTjDA-TF-8bisVsyuMyt-3g2hJI/edit#gid=0

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: I'll take a look at it tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks. Looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the data is sorted by user and date as in the example:

```
=ArrayFormula(to_date(vlookup(row(A2:A),filter({row(A2:A),A2:A},
countifs(row(A2:A),row(A2:A)-1,B2:B,B2:B,A2:A,">"&eomonth(A2:A,-2))=0),2,true)))
```

[image]

If you can't assume that the data is sorted by user and date, you can try something like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(filter(B2:B&text(A2:A,"YYYYMMDD"),A2:A<>""),
sort(filter({B2:B&text(A2:A,"YYYYMMDD"),A2:A},
countifs(A2:A,"<"&A2:A,B2:B,B2:B,A2:A,">"&eomonth(A2:A,-2))=0,A2:A<>""),1,1),2,true))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
This formula only works correctly if each user’s entries are in order. How to make it work regardless of the sorting of records?
Please see the example - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HSbqxmDqE0qzL6vIwTjDA-TF-8bisVsyuMyt-3g2hJI/edit#gid=0

Comment: Well you can probably do it by using the user name and date as a lookup instead of the row number but it would be more messy. In fact, not sure it would help, but can we now assume that all entries are sorted by date and then user name?

Comment: Data is sorted by date and not sorted by the user.